# Add geometry to warped / curved surface - best technique?

Tags: modifiers, geometry, shrinkwrap

I am working on a ring. It will be 3D printed, I am working with SVG graphics that I import, and then extrude. I'd like to add some geometry along the sides of the ring (as seen in the example picture below).

[image]

What would you recommend as the most effective way to properly warp some additional geometry, so that it follows the contours of the ring's side?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XYuno3DgAo&ab_channel=DupliVerts

I've followed this tutorial where I parent some geometry to a plane, and then use the Surface deform modifier on this geometry, with the plane as the target.I then apply a shrinkwrap modifier to this plane, and choose my ring geometry as the target.

[image]

[image]
Can someone explain to me why the geometry is so awful? I've made sure to subdivide my initial geometry plenty to make sure it's smooth. I've also subdivided the plane used for the geometry several levels. And of course, the mesh that I have it shrinkwrapped onto has been subdivided and retopologized and has all scale transforms applied.

I've also retopologized my siding geometry using Quadremesher so that it's free of n-gons and other messy things.

Also as the plane approaches the bottom of the ring, the geometry gets all funky. Any advice here?

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions on what I can do to fix this? Or get better results? or an alternative?

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried filling the n-gon and then pressing `i` to inset.

Comment: For 3D printing: subdivide heavily and sculpt / displace using a texture. (Displace using geonodes to apply it)